# Remove the output of the garbage collector gc() in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a Rmarkdown document where the garbage collector is used to save memory during renderization. The function `gc()` is called at the end of some code chunks for convenience, but I would like to hide its output, while showing other code in the same chunk (e.g. a plot). If this output is impossible to hide without using `eval=FALSE` or `include=FALSE` (eg. with `gc()` in a separate chunk), then I would like to understand *why*, and if this might happen for other functions as well.

Example code to reproduce the problem is given below:

````
---
title: "Example"
output:
  html_document
---

```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library("tidyverse")
```


```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
df <- mtcars %>% dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>% dplyr::summarise(meanMPG = mean(mpg))
df %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=cyl, y=meanMPG))
rm(df); gc(verbose = FALSE, full = FALSE)
```
````

EDIT: as you can note, the problem persist even when the options `verbose=FALSE` and `full=FALSE` are used in `gc()`.

Comment: save it `tmp <- gc()` or `invisible(gc())` chunk option `results='hide'` will also work

Comment: Well, this is a actually an answer. It works, thank you!

Comment: I tried wrapping `suppressMessages` but it didn't work either.